# @ResponseBody annotation reseting headers on response

Tags: java, spring, http

I'm using Spring 3.0 and have something like the following

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/someUrl")
public String handleSomeUrl(@RequestParam(required = true) Long someId){
    // ...
    return someString;
}
```

I have an interceptor with a postHandle that gets called and sets a few no cache headers on the response. However, when the response gets back to the browser, all these cache headers are gone. The funny thing is that if I remove the @ResponseBody annotation and use a response writer instead, I see the headers set by the interceptor. Why is @ResponseBody overriding my headers?

Note:

If I do the following I also see the correct headers on my response. This is doing the exact same thing as my interceptor's postHandle.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/someUrl")
public String handleSomeUrl(@RequestParam(required = true) Long someId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    return someString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be related to this [open issue.](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6559).  It has the following comment:

> I don't think it's wise to mix and
>   math the use of HttpServletResponse
>   and @ResponseBody.

Comment: In my original case, I don't have a HttpServletResponse as a method parameter, so the issue seems a little different. But that open issues definitely helps, and makes me think that maybe the HttpMethodConverter is doing something unintended.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just add those headers on preHandle method (as Spring commits response before postHandle fires, so adding them in postHandle will not work for response returned from @ResponseBody marked controller method):

```
public class ControllerHandleInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
       if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
          response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
          response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
          response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); 
       }

       return true;
    }

    // other code...
}
```